# In flutter while I am running app on iOS simulator screen is getting black while I am testing build ask in Android phones it is working fine

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

[image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdUVT.png)

[image]

Everything is fine while running flutter doctor command

Comment: can you add the screenshot of both android and iphone screen?

Comment: sure, I am adding it

Comment: Add you code as well of that screen !!

Comment: Added Rahul ji, let me know if you need anything more

Comment: you did not add the photo of iphone emulator and also write the code in the block and not the photo of the code Rajeev !!